# Vertex color applied on curves with geometry nodes wont display on Solid Flat in Blender 3.5

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, vertex-colors, toon-shading

On Blender 3.4.1, after applying a geometry nodes modifier with a set vertex color to a curve, you can display that curve with flat vertex color on the *Solid > Flat > Attribute*.

[image: Comparison Between Blender 3.4.1 and 3.5]

However, from blender 3.5 and upwards, it doesn’t displays vertex color applied to curves anymore, instead it only shows black.

One way to display it, is on the *Viewport shading > Material Preview* by connecting the Color Attribute to the *Base Color* input of a material, but this displays the vextex color on a lit condition, and doesn’t looks flat.

[image: Material Preview visualization fix]

This is the geometry nodes setup that was used to apply vertex color to curves back in blender 3.4.1

[image: Applying Vertex Color to curves with Geometry Nodes]

I would like this feature back to visualize a character’s hair color with a flat shaded look, using editable curves and without having to convert curves into mesh.

Comment: Have You found any solution ( beside attr.color -> material color )?